# The great battery swap

Tags: physics, survival, ethics, antimatter

An alien contra-organization wants to spur the development of Earth to help humans in the near-future in presence of a prime-directive like law. They cannot establish actual contact, so they do the next best thing: covertly deliver some important technology.

Unfortunately they do something not-so-clever here. Assume our secret organization replaces some percentage of batteries P with new, upgraded batteries that do the following:

- About 90% of the mass of the new battery is antimatter (the technology is very miniaturized, so most of the 10% is the outer shell for point 3).
- It converts this into energy using the matter in air at near-100% efficiency.
- It looks exactly the same as the old battery from the outside, and performs the same, with the caveat that:
- The new battery never seems to run dry...

The replaced batteries are completely random, and could be anywhere. In multi-cell batteries, each cell has its own probability P of being swapped. We also assume the replacement happens at-once. Exactly how that is done is left unanswered and isn't the point of the question.

A problem arises when somehow one of the new batteries is destroyed. The result is a large thermonuclear explosion (minus the fallout). A standard AA battery would produce about a 1.25 MT-equivalent, a 9V battery would produce a 1.87 MT blast. For the P=1 case: a Tesla pack weighs 540 kg. that's about 24 GT.

If we plot the human survival rate R against the probability P, we know two points: at P < 10^-10, R = 1, as it's likely that nothing happens. At P = 1, R ~ 0. It's likely the only survivors are in very isolated places. Say: in space, aboard a submarine, aboard a ship that isn't in the very busy shipping lanes ,rainforest natives, or the antarctic as any battery that explodes sets off a giant chain reaction.

Our organization wants to know, what would be an optimal P? Thus, they want to know: what would the graph look like in-between these two P values?

Comment: Considering chain reactions between exploding batteries, for these purposes R is never 0 as there will be large enough gaps between human habitations that the chain won't reach all areas. Batteries are not evenly distributed across the planet. Specifically these will be very rural regions that are more independent of "central civilisation" and hence more likely to be able to survive and repopulate. Equally your chain reaction is unlikely to be able to cross large oceans, so you could easily exterminate a large portion of Europe independently of East Asia or Australia.

Comment: It is true a single chain reaction won't reach everywhere. But consider that it's likely multiple batteries are destroyed before people know about the dangers... I also say R ~0, not R = 0. Basically, a negligible fraction of people survive.

Comment: Certainly you'd lose a few cities, but the blast radius isn't actually that large from batteries in household goods, only up to 3miles. The bigger issue would be car batteries, UPSs etc. What would be the blast radius from a Tesla for example. Even then, if London went boom, Scotland could be fine, there's a lot of empty space.

Comment: Query: many large batteries like laptop batteries are actually collections of smaller lithium ion battery cells. ( http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AnPIzc2j-nc/UZo_wGD2NoI/AAAAAAAAAsM/qbtJOjTkQIo/s1600/2013-05-19+19.49.03.jpg )

Do all cells convert or is each battery cell independent. 

It would increase the number of batteries dramatically but decrease individual blast size.

Comment: One thing to consider: If two batteries explode that are very close together, the resulting blast is the same as if one single battery with twice the mass exploded. If you packed 1000 firecrackers together and set that off the blast is going to be bigger than if you set off a single one. But, if P < 1, then each cell is considered individually here. (I have to make a distinction at some level; there's grid-scale battery storage in the world too...)

Comment: I have the impression that is a pure probability problem and that, with a slight rephrasing, might find a better and more formal answer on mathematic.SE

Comment: Do you know how battery in Prius look like? Typical Prius have 28 cells. In the 2009 26k priuses in Los angeles. 26k times 28. That make your swap not only more probably for the metropolis areas but also make the size of the fallout (effect of chain reaction) bigger. For example there are more priuses (not to mention other electric cars) in New York then are in Poland.

Comment: are these covert inserts, invisible on xray, etc, or will the first person to be xrayed with one (airport, pacemaker surgery, product reverse engineering) uncover the switch (and thereby give rise to a global search effort)? (we would never guess from the explosions, even coin cells would have far too much oomph).

Comment: also, can you explain the plan again? secret organisation deploys super-batteries everywhere, humans blow themselves up in huge numbers (landfills ignite cities, which ignite the suburbs, well travelled roads act as det cord...)/find the batteries ... profit?

Comment: I'm not sure an X-ray would reveal much: matter and antimatter behave symetrically w.r.t. x-rays. It's likely there'd be a diffrence with unswapped samples, but every type would have its own signature to compare to... But why go through all that when there is a far simpler test: try to empty the battery.